# How to get photos/videos from my iphone into the cloud easily

Tags: data-synchronization, photos

I make photos every day. I want them to be kept somewhere safe (online, not on my computer), without having to think about it.  Either over 3g, or whenever I'm near a wifi, I want my videos and photos to automatically upload.

Ideally to smugmug.com, so I don't need to take additional steps to share a subset of the photos, but something like dropbox or s3 would also do.

I find it hard to believe I'm the only one with this problem, but I haven't been able to find a good solution yet. (Best thing so far: PhotoSync with flickr sync)

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry, Apple says it's coming in [iCloud](http://www.apple.com/icloud/what-is.html)

Answer (score 0):

You suggest Dropbox yourself, so I am not sure what alternative solution you are looking for?

On my Android I can save photos to a specific Dropbox folder.
Result: it is automatically synched to my computer and stored online as well. In addition you can publicly share dropbox folders, so other people are able to look at your pictures as well.

The only thing you still have to do (which you probably won't with iCloud) is saving your photos specifically in a dropbox folder.